# NW JS Node JS executing command on Windows XP

Tags: node.js, cmd, windows-xp, node-webkit

I'm developing a desktop application with NWJS and I'm trying to execute a command to get a property of a file but It's not working on any Computer with Windows XP, here is the code:

On Windows 7 and 8 it works just fine, I get the property but on Win XP doesn't do anything... no error, no alert, ANYTHING, it simply does nothing.
But if a copy/paste the code in a cmd terminal it works.

```
home.executeWinCmd = function () {

    console.log('executing command');

    var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('cmd');

    terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    terminal.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    terminal.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Sending stdin to terminal');

        var command = '';

        if($scope.config != undefined) {
            if($scope.config.clientPath == undefined) {
                command = 'wmic datafile where name="' + $scope.config.clientPath + '" get version\n';
            } else {
                command = 'wmic datafile where name="C:\\\\Clients\\\\StaClient.exe" get version\n';
            }
        } else {
            command = 'wmic datafile where name="C:\\\\Clients\\\\StaClient.exe" get version\n';
        }

        console.log('command ' + command);
        terminal.stdin.write(command);

        terminal.stdin.end();
    }, 1000);

}
```

**EDIT 1**
This is working now... for some reason.

Now this code does not work, which is essentially the same, when I use exec, it simply does nothing, no err no stderr, no stdout, nothing. This is really troubling

```
NodeModules.exec('wmic datafile where name="' + $scope.config.clientPath + '" get version', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        Logger.log('ERRR', 'Error executing command: ' + err);
        return;
    }

    if (stderr.length > 0) {
        console.log(stderr);
        Logger.log('ERRR', 'No Client Present return from stderr: ' + stderr);
        $scope.timeout = $timeout($scope.timeoutFn, 3000);
        return;
    }

    $scope.config.currentVersion = (stdout.substring('Version '.length, stdout.length)).trim();
    $scope.config.phase = Enums.Phase.CHECK_RECENT;
    Logger.log('REPR', 'Current Version ' + $scope.config.currentVersion);

});
```

Comment: Is it a "run as administrator" problem?

Comment: tried already. still doesn't work

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich did you end up finding a solution? I'm experiencing a similar issue today running `wmic OS get Caption` on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: I ended up using Electron (Atom Shell) ... but I think the problem was related to permissions

Comment: Thank you @GabrielMatusevich